# What is the full form of 'ddspth' in oracle sql?

Tags: oracle

Can anyone explain the full form of "ddsp" in oracle sql command?

Comment: I searched the question, as I am a fresher I saw a pile of question similar in this topic tagged as 'sql-server'. So without knowing, I tagged my question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a spelled number.

```
SQL> select sysdate,
  2         to_char(sysdate, 'ddsp') ex1
  3  from dual;

SYSDATE  EX1
-------- ------------
27.02.20 twenty-seven

SQL>
```

More info in any Oracle documentation, e.g. [DATE_FORMAT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_commands_1029.htm#OLADM780)

Comment: Thank you for explaining and  suggesting the Oracle documentation. I got the precise answer of my question.